# Open a menu from a click on static (c++)

Tags: c++, windows

I created a window without title bar and I am trying to add a menu but it appears above my window.
This is my window creation:

```
WNDCLASS wc = { 0 };
    wc.lpfnWndProc = SProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInst;
    wc.lpszClassName = "test";
    wc.hbrBackground = NULL;
    wc.style = CS_DROPSHADOW;
    wc.hCursor = carrow;
    if (!RegisterClass(&wc))
        return 1;

    HWnd = CreateWindow(wc.lpszClassName,
        "Compta",
        WS_POPUP|WS_VISIBLE|WS_CLIPCHILDREN,
        10, 10, 1000, 800, 0, 0, hInst, NULL);
```

And the menu:

```
HMENU hMenubar;
HMENU hMenu;

hMenubar = CreateMenu();
hMenu = CreateMenu();

AppendMenuW(hMenu, MF_STRING, 1111, L"&New");
AppendMenuW(hMenu, MF_STRING, 1112, L"&Open");
AppendMenuW(hMenu, MF_SEPARATOR, 0, NULL);
AppendMenuW(hMenu, MF_STRING, 1113, L"&Quit");

AppendMenuW(hMenubar, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR) hMenu, L"&File");
SetMenu(hwnd, hMenubar);
```

The best would be to have no menu bar (as I want my own background untouched) and I would create a static with a simple text, and on click, the menu appears just below the text. Is it possible or I need to create my own custom menu with another child ?
Thanks

Comment: Use a [popup menu](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648003(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Of course, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correction of my code and solution to my question:

```
HMENU hMenu;

hMenu = CreatePopupMenu();

AppendMenuW(hMenu, MF_STRING, 1111, L"&New");
AppendMenuW(hMenu, MF_STRING, 1112, L"&Open");
AppendMenuW(hMenu, MF_SEPARATOR, 0, NULL);
AppendMenuW(hMenu, MF_STRING, 1113, L"&Quit");

TrackPopupMenuEx(hMenu,TPM_LEFTALIGN|TPM_TOPALIGN,100,18,hwnd,0);
```